Is it possible to pipe a file into heredoc in bash?
I'm able to zip a file, upload it, and expand it into a directory on a server like so:
tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 'cd /some-path/ && tar -zxf -'

Is it possible to do the same thing with heredoc? Something like the following (which doesn't work):
tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 /bin/bash <<EOF
    cd /some-path/
    tar -zxf -
EOF

Justification: I have a bunch of local scripts I'm running over SSH on two servers that treat quotes differently, and heredoc fixes that issue. However, several of the scripts pipe files though pipe viewer to the server so I can monitor progress, and I've not been able to find a way to pipe the contents of a local file into pv and then into a heredoc expression so that I can manipulate that file on the server (like I can without heredoc).
EDIT
It also needs to support expansion so I can read values from a config file, which is why the above justification/link mentions quotes being an issue:
root_path=`jq -r '.config.path.remote' config.json`
tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 "cd '$root_path' && tar -zxf -"

and (again, not working, but the expansion works):
root_path=`jq -r '.config.path.remote' config.json`
tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 /bin/bash <<EOF
    cd "$root_path"
    tar -zxf -
EOF


The here-doc is being processed on the local system, not the remote system. It's providing input to the local tar command, but it's not reading from stdin.

Each process can only have stdin connected to one place. It can come from the heredoc, or it can come from the pipeline, but not both at the same time.

now, if you had a normal-ish shell we could copy the original stdin off to a different fd before setting up a remote heredoc, but because this whole thing came into play because you have an unusual shell all bets are off unless we can identify that shell to reason about its specific behavior.

...speaking of which, have you tried inspecting the system with atypical behavior to try to figure out the underlying cause? Any luck in that effort?

If the problem is with quotes, why is the original command having problems? There are no quotes in the command you're sending over SSH.

@Barmar above is a dumbed-down version: in the actual script I'm reading values as variables from a .json config file (e.g. "/some-path/" is a variable with the server's root directory in it).

@CharlesDuffy the system with atypical behavior is a standard WP Engine host, so there's likely not much I can do to have them change things, but I do wonder why they strip quotes in such an odd way.

It's worth figuring that out. If they're passing content direct to a shell we can figure out what that shell's behavior is. If they're using some custom code to try to do shell-like parsing (maybe as an attempt to look for commands sent by common malware or such -- the wordpress ecosystem is a popular attack target) before content gets passed off to an actual shell... well, again, we can't come up with a good workaround until we know exactly what it is we're working around.

Often, sshd_config files are world-readable -- if they have a ForceCommand in there you may be able to read it even from your unprivileged user account.

BTW, once you have an answer that was correct for the question as it was asked when that answer was written, it's improper to edit the question in a way that invalidates the answer later (you may find people here referring to questions that change in such ways as "chameleon questions"). Click the accept button, and ask a new question for the new case.

If your remote shell were bash (and your local shell were bash 5.0 or later), I'd suggest tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 "cd ${root_path@Q} && tar -zxf -". Or, better, tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 "tar -C ${root_path@Q} -xzf -"

BTW, if you prepend set -x; to the remote command, as in, tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 "set -x; tar -C ${root_path@Q} -xzf -", is that honored? (It should cause the remote shell to print a log message describing the arguments it passed to tar).

As pointed out in a comment, you can't have two different standard inputs. If the shell gets its stdin from the here-doc, it can't pass the SSH connection as stdin to the tar command.
You don't need to send cd and tar as separate command separated by &&. You can use the -C option to tar to have it change directory by itself. This option is in both GNU tar and BSD tar, although it's not in the POSIX specification.
With this, there's no quoting needed at all (unless there are spaces in the path you're changing to).
tar -pzcf - example.txt | ssh user@198.123.45.678 tar -C /some-path/ -zxf -


I'm not sure the former would work as currently written: you're starting up bash with stdin connected to a temporary file with the heredoc contents. How is tar going to get a file handle on the original stdin? If you saved a copy of the original fd, that should work, but IIRC the OP had a prior question implying that their default remote shell was something unusual and surprising on a subset of the systems they needed to be able to run code on.

Oh, you're right!

So what they probably need is ssh server bash -c 'cd blah && tar -zxf -'

To paraphrase Barbie: "Distributed computing is hard!"

nod. If it's GNU tar they can even ditch the cd and use tar -C blah -xzf -

BSD (e.g. MacOS) tar also has that, so probably most tars in the wild. Although if the default shell isn't compatible with his original command, who knows what tar it has?

I'd probably skip the bash -c here; the point of explicitly running bash was to get a well-understood parser, but since we don't know what the outer shell is (but do know that it's un-POSIX-y) and so can't reliably craft quoting intended to get data passed through it, keeping the command as simple as possible (depending on nothing more than splitting on spaces) is probably to the better.

Then we're essentially back to the original command, except that we replaced cd blah && tar to tar -C blah

But I've simplified the result like that.

The OP's earlier question had nested quotes that a subset of the OP's remote systems parsed incorrectly. Those aren't present here, so we shouldn't need the workaround for noncompliant quote handling. I think they took a solution and tried to apply it outside the problem domain it was intended for.

There are many uses of sudo and ssh where it can be extremely difficult to get all the quoting and escaping right (the worst may be the combination ssh hostname sudo ...). I've probably posted an answer at [unix.se] where a here-doc was the solution. I usually recommend that they copy a script to the remote, then execute the script using ssh, rather than try to combine everything. Unfortunately, they usually say this isn't possible.

When the remote shell is bash, I consider ssh somehost "$(declare -f funcname); $(declare -p var1 var2 var3); funcname" a quite solid solution (assuming the function funcname depends on variables var1, var2 and var3).
